# understanding session.get vs session.load method in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session, transactions

I am not able to understand the difference between load and get . the following piece of code doesn't work when i give session.load. It gives null pointer exception. But same does work when i am using session.get() .

```
public Employee getEmployee(final String id){        
        HibernateCallback callback = new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) 
                throws HibernateException,SQLException {
                //return (Employee)session.load(Employee.class, id);   doesn't work
                  return (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, id);    //it works
            }
        };        
        return (Employee)hibernateTemplate.execute(callback);
    }
```

**I also want to understand how Session object is passed to doInHibernate.?

when does session starts and when it ends?**

Stack trace is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:862)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:781)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(HibernateTemplate.java:1282)
    at $Proxy0.load(Unknown Source)
    at hibernate.EmployeeDao$1.doInHibernate(EmployeeDao.java:25)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at hibernate.EmployeeDao.getEmployee(EmployeeDao.java:29)
    at hibernate.SpringHibernateTest.main(SpringHibernateTest.java:26)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's the line causing a NullPointerException?

Comment: Google for "at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:372)". You're running an old version of Hibernate, and I found several possible reasons for this exception (bad mapping, bad jars, etc.). It doesn't have much to do with load vs get.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Thanks a lot!!! I will check my build configuration and will update the old jars I have many times face this problem and am learning to mavenize the projects... but can you please help me with other doubts .i.e. **how Session object is passed to doInHibernate.?
when does session starts and when it ends?**

Comment: It depends on your Spring configuration. Normally, if running inside a spring transaction, it starts at the beginning of the transaction and ends at the end. If not running in a transaction, it exists only for the duration of the doInHibernate method call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
I am not able to understand the difference between load and get
```

The main difference is: if load() can’t find the object in the cache or database, an exception is thrown. The load() method never returns null. The get() method returns 
null if the object can’t be found.
Other difference is that the load() method may return a proxy instead of a real instance but get() never does return proxy.

```
the following piece of code doesn't work when i give session.load. It gives null pointer exception. But same does work when i am using session.get() .
```

If object is not found, load method will throw exception but get won't.Simple

**Edit:**
To elaborate the things,

1. When get() method is called, it will directly hit the database, fetch the result and return. If no matching fields are found, it will gladly return null.
2. But when load() executes, firstly it will search the cache for required object. If found, all is well. But if object is not found in cache, load() method will return a proxy. You can consider this proxy as a shortcut for database query execution. Remember, no database hit is made yet. Now when you actually access the object the proxy will be traced and database hit will be made.

Lets consider a simple example.

```
User user=(User)session.load(User.class, new Long(1));//Line 1
System.out.println(user.getPassword());//Line 2
```

If User object with primary key 1 is not available in session, the load() method will set a proxy for the database at Line 1. Now when actual value of the 'user' object is called, i.e. line 2, the proxy will be traced and the database will be hit.

Hope this will help.

Comment: No: load doesn't lookup the object in database. It returns the object it has in its session cache, or creates a proxy, assuming the object exists in the database.

Comment: @Pravin: I already read this from manual I wanted someone to explain me the meaning of what you just told ..when it is said that load method returns proxy instead of real instance then I understand that it returns the data from some cache and thus load method doesn't require multiple data hits to database.Also I do understand that null pointer exception occurs when a null value is being referenced, my question was why it was null and how can I make it work with load so your answer was not at all helpfull

Comment: @Anupam, I have edited the post to make the things clearer. I hope this will recover the rep I had lost.

Comment: @Pravin My jar collection is obsolete and screwing my stuff .. and thanks for updating the answer...I returned your lost reps