# why hibernate session.load returns proxied instance of object

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I tried to load an object from session with id that doesn't exist and got empty object. When I try to get it's parameters, I get exception. I can't understand what's the purpose of returning proxy instance and what precedence does it take over session.get method?

Comment: as you haven't added code and hbm but still I will try to answer, if you are trying to access/load it after session is closed then it will give you the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924799/understanding-session-get-vs-session-load-method-in-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: Why? Because that's what the method is supposed to do, and documented to do. Why would you want that? Because, for example, you want to insert an entity A containing a reference (ManyToOne) to another entity B without needing to actually load the B state from the database: the ID of B is sufficient.